# Parsing JSON into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml

Can anyone help me parsing the XML content present in Oracle DB with BLOB. And Display it in UI with HTML Table using Angular JS.

From Oracle DB whenever I Query a field ,it will return multiple ROW with BLOB

And Each Blob contains XML data. Now I want to Parse it from AngularJS.

Here What I have tried

I am getting the XML Response from php and sending it to Sitemap.xml and accessing that in AngularJS

Since I have 3 ROWS returning from database , I am getting 3 XML tags like below

```
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "1">
            <Person:OrderStatus>RED</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>A</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "2">
            <Person:OrderStatus>GREEN</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>B</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "3">
            <Person:OrderStatus>RED</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>C</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
```

Now I want to convert it into JSON using ANGULAR JS and Display the Values in HTML TABLE. Can you please help me

AngularJS

```
    var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);
    app.controller('httpController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("Sitemap.xml",
                {
                    transformResponse: function (cnv) {
                        var x2js = new X2JS();
                        var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv);
                        return aftCnv;
                    }
                })
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

And My UI Should look as HTML Table like

```
   <table>
  <tr>
    <th>WorkOrder</th>
    <th>OrderStatus</th>
    <th>OrderType</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1<br></td>
    <td>RED</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>GREEN</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>RED</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have XML and you want to produce HTML. What does JSON have to do with anything?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. While your XML comes from a BLOB and you're using PHP server-side to retrieve it, the question has nothing whatsoever to do with blobs or PHP. It's a question about client-side JavaScript using Angular operating on XML. I've removed irrelevant tags and added [tag:javascript]. I didn't remove [tag:json] pending your clarifying what JSON has to do with this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since My XML data is very large I have given here sample , So I want it to have it JSON before parsing and also Parsing JSON is easy in Angular JS

Comment: help with what? You haven't identified what problem is in code shown

Comment: Currently I am getting 3 XML tag now I need to convert to JSON and Parse So I need help in the approach for Angular JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to myself.
The Problem was the XML is having multiple root elements so it wasn't converted to JSON.

As a work around now I am Appending my XML with  So Now I am able to convert it into JSON

```
<Persons>
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "1">
            <Person:OrderStatus>RED</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>A</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "2">
            <Person:OrderStatus>GREEN</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>B</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
<Person:PersonEvent xmlns:Person = "http://PERSON/PersonEvent">
    <Person:Body>
        <Person:WorkOrder workOrderId = "3">
            <Person:OrderStatus>RED</Person:OrderStatus>
            <Person:OrderType>C</Person:OrderType>
        </Person:WorkOrder>
    </Person:Body>
</Person:PersonEvent>
</Persons>
```